# Automatically generated code throws syntax error

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax, ms-access-2010

My problem is that an automatically generated SQL code throws syntax error. Although it seems to run properly, but it can be disturbing that I see the syntax error message every time I click on that column.

The code is:

```
SELECT
   Daily_Output20151013.[Hinmei/Hinsyu],
   [Defect Detail Information List].[Find Process Name],
   Sum(Daily_Output20151013.[Outgoing Qty]) AS [SumOfOutgoing Qty],
   Sum([Defect Detail Information List].[Defect Qty]) AS [SumOfDefect Qty],
   Sum([Defect Detail Information List].[Modify Qty]) AS [SumOfModify Qty],
   IIf([Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD143S" Or [Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD111S","HP",IIf([Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD122V" Or [Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD082HD","HD","Common")) AS [Group]
FROM [Defect Detail Information List]
INNER JOIN Daily_Output20151013 
   ON (Daily_Output20151013.[Ledger No] = [Defect Detail Information List].[Ledger No]) 
  AND ([Defect Detail Information List].[Order Class] = Daily_Output20151013.[Order Class]) 
  AND (Daily_Output20151013.[Unit No] = [Defect Detail Information List].[Unit Lot No]) 
  AND (Daily_Output20151013.[Hinmei/Hinsyu] = [Defect Detail Information List].[Hinmei-Hinsyu Name]) 
  AND ([Defect Detail Information List].[Lot No] = Daily_Output20151013.[Lot No])
GROUP BY 
   Daily_Output20151013.[Hinmei/Hinsyu],
   [Defect Detail Information List].[Find Process Name],
   IIf([Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD143S" Or [Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD111S","HP",IIf([Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD122V" Or [Hinmei/Hinsyu]="Unit SD082HD","HD","Common"));
```

The column which I have problem with is [Find Process Name].

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Just because some code has been automatically generated doesn't have to mean it's correct. There could be bugs in the generator. Talking about "generator", how is the SQL query you show "generated"? From where? Is the specification used by the generator correct in the first place?

Comment: It is "generated" in the way I was not writing it directly, just were clicking with Access, and Access generated the SQL code. The specification is correct, if we don't watch de syntax. It runs properly, but every time I click on [Find Process Name] column, it throws syntax error (after that it doesn't exit, but runs properly, but it's quite disturbing, so I would like to solve the problem).

Comment: And you do have such a column in the table?

Comment: Basically it's a query using a table that includes this column (so the answer is yes).

Comment: Please add some details. You created this query in the Access query designer, yes? When exactly is the error shown? What is the exact (and full) error message?

Comment: Yes. The error message was: ,,Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression: FindProcessName''